# How to pass image and JSON together from React and get from req.body in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cloudinary

In the frontend I'm passing some data, lets' say

```
{
 title: "Test Title",
 price: 100,
 media: {uid: 'rc-upload-1627793182603-11', lastModified: 1627745801648, lastModifiedDate: Sat Jul 31 2021 21:06:41 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), name: 'sweet-corn-min.jpg', size: 50890, thumbUrl: "data:image/png;base64,........"}
}
```

In the nodejs server I'm taking this through req.body. But when I try to upload to cloudinary

```
await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
    media.thumbUrl,
    { folder: process.env.STORE_NAME }, //Uploads to Specific Store Folder
    async (err, result) => {
      imageUrls.push(result.secure_url);
    }
  );
```

Here currently I'm using thumbUrl to upload into server. But this reduces the size to 200*200. Is there any another way to upload to cloudinary from this data?

**FIXED THE ISSUE, NOW I"M PASSING BASE64 DATA to BACKEND**

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, you are sending a request with a file and json metadata from React client to your nodejs server, where you extract the file and send it to cloudinary?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send both JSON and a file in 1 request, it would be best to use `multipart/form-data` request. As the name suggests, one part of the request will be the JSON object and the other your file in binary format. The advantage of doing this is that you **save bytes** when sending such a request (apart maybe with very tiny file sizes, because there is a small overhead to a multipart request). **Base64 encoding increases size** of data by [33-36%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) so sending the file in binary format can make a huge difference.

Then on your server, you extract the file part from the request and pass it as byte array buffer to cloudinary's `upload` method in the `file` argument.